# Derive parent-child hierarchy from an array using DataWeave (additional details)

Tags: java, mule, dataweave, mule4

This is a follow up to an [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75332945/derive-parent-child-hierarchy-from-an-array-using-dataweave) question. Thanks @harshank for the quick help. I am posting this question separately since there was an additional check required which I had not asked in the earlier question. So, the solution posted earlier works fine for the stated requirement.

I am adding the additional requirement here:

1. The decision if `gp` and `parent` match depends on an additional attribute `eye_colour` (please see sample payload below).
2. Also in the response additional fields need to be populated (which was not mentioned in the earlier question). Things like `name` and `eye_colour`.

So, as an example this is the payload:

```json
[
  {
    "gp": "T1",
    "gp_eye_colour": "blue",
    "gp_name" : "John",
    "parent": "T1",
    "parent_eye_colour" : "black",
    "parent_name" : "Sam",
    "child": "C1",
    "child_eye_colour" : "brown",
    "child_name" : "C1"

  },
 {
    "gp": "T1",
    "gp_eye_colour": "blue",
    "gp_name" : "John",
    "parent": "T1",
    "parent_eye_colour" : "black",
    "parent_name" : "Sam",
    "child": "C1",
    "child_eye_colour" : "brown",
    "child_name" : "C1"

  }
  
]
```

And now using the earlier solution, I have tried to build on top of it as:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
// hierarchy's structure. If, lets say you add a "grand child" it should work. (haven't tested this though)
var hierarchy = {
    gp: {
        parent: {
            child: null
        }
    }
}
fun getDirectGeanologies(records, hierarchyStructure,isGp,isParent,isChild) = do {
    var topLevel = keysOf(hierarchyStructure)[0] as String
    var secondLevel = keysOf(hierarchyStructure[topLevel])[0]
    ---
    (records groupBy $[topLevel])
        mapObject ((level1Childs, code) -> 
            genealogy: {
                code: code,
                eye_colour: if(isGp) (level1Childs.gp_eye_colour) else if(isParent) (level1Childs.parent_eye_colour) else (level1Childs.child_eye_colour),
                name: if(isGp) (level1Childs.gp_name) else if(isParent) (level1Childs.parent_name) else (level1Childs.child_name),
                hierarchy:
                    if(secondLevel != null) // If there are no more childs, do nothing.
                        (level1Childs groupBy ((item) -> item[secondLevel] ~= code) // This is to handle when parent = gp
                            mapObject ((value, hasSameParent) -> 
                                // If parent = gp, we want to skip parent and link directly to child
                                if(hasSameParent as Boolean) getDirectGeanologies(value, hierarchyStructure[topLevel][secondLevel],false,false,true) 
                                // recurrsively call the function with child records and going down the hierarchyStructure by one
                                else getDirectGeanologies(value, hierarchyStructure[topLevel],false,true,false) 
                        ))
                    else {}
            }
        )
}

---
list: getDirectGeanologies(payload,hierarchy,true,false,false)
```

However, it is generating duplicate elements for `eye_colour` and `name`. Ideally, it should print the values only once with the value of either gp / parent / child.

This is the expected response:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<list>
  <genealogy>
    <code>T1</code>
    <eye_colour>blue</eye_colour>
    <name>John</name>
    <hierarchy>
      <genealogy>
        <code>C1</code>
        <eye_colour>brown</eye_colour>
        <name>C1</name>
        <hierarchy/>
      </genealogy>
    </hierarchy>
  </genealogy>
</list>
```

I was also not able to figure out how to check if gp and parent have same values based on two fields (`gp & gp_eye_colour` vs `parent & parent_eye_colour`)

Thank you @sudhish_s for the response, adding an example to elaborate regarding decision of when to skip parent (when `gp & gp_eye_colour` of gp are same as `parent & parent_eye_colour` of parent).

Sample input: (Here parent `Sam` should *not* be skipped since though gp and parent are same their eye colours are different. Similarly, in case of `Don`, this parent should be skipped since gp and parent *and* their eye colours are the same).

```json
[
  {
    "gp": "T1",
    "gp_eye_colour": "blue",
    "gp_name" : "John",
    "parent": "T1",
    "parent_eye_colour" : "black",
    "parent_name" : "Sam",
    "child": "C1",
    "child_eye_colour" : "brown",
    "child_name" : "C1"

  },
 {
    "gp": "T1",
    "gp_eye_colour": "blue",
    "gp_name" : "John",
    "parent": "T1",
    "parent_eye_colour" : "blue",
    "parent_name" : "Don",
    "child": "C1",
    "child_eye_colour" : "brown",
    "child_name" : "C1"
  }  
]
```

Here is the expected response:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<list>
  <genealogy>
    <code>T1</code>
    <eye_colour>blue</eye_colour>
    <name>John</name>
    <hierarchy>
      <genealogy>
        <code>T1</code>
        <eye_colour>black</eye_colour>
        <name>Sam</name>
        <hierarchy>
          <genealogy>
            <code>C1</code>
            <eye_colour>brown</eye_colour>
            <name>C1</name>
            <hierarchy/>
          </genealogy>
        </hierarchy>
      </genealogy>
      <genealogy>
        <code>C1</code>
        <eye_colour>brown</eye_colour>
        <name>C1</name>
        <hierarchy/>
      </genealogy>
    </hierarchy>
  </genealogy>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different version. Used arrays for reference.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var hierarchy = ["gp", "parent", "child"]
fun getDirectGeanologies(records, level) = do {
    var hLevel = hierarchy[level]
    ---
    records groupBy $[hLevel] mapObject ((children, code) -> 
        genealogy: {
            code: code,
            eye_colour: children[0][hLevel ++ "_eye_colour"],
            name: children[0][hLevel ++ "_name"],
            hierarchy: 
                if (level == sizeOf(hierarchy) - 1) {}
                else do {
                    var nextLevel = level + 1
                    var nextGen = children groupBy ($[hierarchy[nextLevel]])
                    --- 
                    nextGen mapObject ((nextGenChildren, nextGenCode) -> 
                        if (nextGenCode == code)
                            getDirectGeanologies (nextGenChildren, nextLevel + 1 )
                        else
                            getDirectGeanologies (nextGenChildren, nextLevel)
                    )                   
                }
                                            
        }
    )
}
---
list: getDirectGeanologies(payload,0)
```

The issue with elements appear multiple times is due to the `level1Childs` is Array. Change the output to `json`, it will be more clear. If you want to use your code, change the `eye_colour` and `name` mapping to below

```
                eye_colour: if(isGp) (level1Childs[0].gp_eye_colour) else if(isParent) (level1Childs[0].parent_eye_colour) else (level1Childs[0].child_eye_colour),
                name: if(isGp) (level1Childs[0].gp_name) else if(isParent) (level1Childs[0].parent_name) else (level1Childs[0].child_name),
```

Comment: Thanks @sudhish_s for this , with a little tweaks was able to achieve desired result  , thank you !