# Derive parent-child hierarchy in JSON from an array using DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Hopefully this is the last of my questions related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75332945/derive-parent-child-hierarchy-from-an-array-using-dataweave) and [this](https://Derive%20parent-child%20hierarchy%20from%20an%20array%20using%20DataWeave%20(additional%20details))

The earlier questions were related to generating XML payload while this query is around generating JSON o/p in a specific format...

Thanks to @Harshank and @sudhish_s was able to make some progress with XML o/p. However I am not able to figure out how to go about json o/p

Here is the input payload ( have limited it to three rows / json objects but could be in thousands)

```
    [
  {
    "gp": "S1",
    "gp_eye_colour": "blue",
    "gp_name" : "John",
    "parent": "S1",
    "parent_eye_colour" : "blue",
    "parent_name" : "Sam",
    "child": "C1",
    "child_eye_colour" : "black",
    "child_name" : "C1-name"
  },
 {
    "gp": "S1",
    "gp_eye_colour": "blue",
    "gp_name" : "John",
    "parent": "P1",
    "parent_eye_colour" : "blue",
    "parent_name" : "Don",
    "child": "C1",
    "child_eye_colour" : "brown",
    "child_name" : "C1-name"
  } ,
  {
    "gp": "S2",
    "gp_eye_colour": "blue",
    "gp_name" : "David",
    "parent": "P2",
    "parent_eye_colour" : "blue",
    "parent_name" : "Martha",
    "child": "C1",
    "child_eye_colour" : "brown",
    "child_name" : "C1-name"
  }  
]
```

Desired o/p is as below :

```
{
    "S2_blue": {
        "code": "S2",
        "eyeColour": "blue",
        "name": "David",
        "hierarchy": [
            {
                "code": "P2",
                "eyeColour": "blue",
                "name": "Martha",
                "hierarchy": [
                    {
                        "code": "C1",
                        "eyeColour": "brown",
                        "name": "C1-name",
                        "hierarchy": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "S1_blue": {
        "code": "S1",
        "eyeColour": "blue",
        "name": "John",
        "hierarchy": [
            {
                "code": "P1",
                "eyeColour": "blue",
                "name": "Don",
                "hierarchy": [
                    {
                        "code": "C1",
                        "eyeColour": "brown",
                        "name": "C1-name",
                        "hierarchy": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "code": "C1",
                "eyeColour": "black",
                "name": "C1-name",
                "hierarchy": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Similar rules need to apply :

1. Its a Grandparent >> Parent >> Child hierarchy
2. If Grandparent and Parent share same characteristics (`gp` == `parent` and `gp_eye_colour` == `parent_eye_colour` then skip parent and directly include child(ren)
   ( as an example parent `Sam` is excluded since `John` (gp) has the same value for `gp` and `eye_colour`
3. `Don` is not exluded ( same rule as above )

Using the solutions provided to the earlier asked questions - I came up with the following code:

```
    %dw 2.0
output application/json
var hierarchy = ["gp", "parent", "child"]
fun getDirectGeanologies(records, level) = do {
    var hLevel = hierarchy[level]
    var xyz =  if(level == 0)
    (records groupBy ((item, index) -> item.gp ++ "_" ++ item.gp_eye_colour) )
    else if(level == 1)
    (records groupBy ((item, index) -> item.parent ++ "_" ++ item.parent_eye_colour))
    else
    (records groupBy ((item, index) -> item.child ++ "_" ++ item.child_eye_colour))
    ---
     xyz mapObject ((children, code) ->      
        (code): {
            code: children[0][hLevel],
            eyeColour: children[0][hLevel ++ "_eye_colour"],
            name: children[0][hLevel ++ "_name"],
            hierarchy:  
                if (level == sizeOf(hierarchy) - 1) [] // if level = 2 ( child stop recursion)
                else do {
                    var nextLevel = level + 1
                    var nextGen = if(nextLevel == 1)(children groupBy ((item, index) -> item.parent ++ "_" ++ item.parent_eye_colour)) else (children groupBy ((item, index) -> item.child ++ "_" ++ item.child_eye_colour))
                    --- 
                    nextGen mapObject ((nextGenChildren, nextGenCode) -> 
                        if (nextGenCode == code)
                            getDirectGeanologies (nextGenChildren, nextLevel + 1 ) // skip parent
                        else
                            getDirectGeanologies (nextGenChildren, nextLevel)
                    )                   
                }
                                                        
        }
    )
}
---
getDirectGeanologies(payload,0)
```

However it is not producing desired o/p :

```
    {
  "S1_blue": {
    "code": "S1",
    "eyeColour": "blue",
    "name": "John",
    "hierarchy": {
      "C1_black": {
        "code": "C1",
        "eyeColour": "black",
        "name": "C1-name",
        "hierarchy": [
          
        ]
      },
      "P1_blue": {
        "code": "P1",
        "eyeColour": "blue",
        "name": "Don",
        "hierarchy": {
          "C1_brown": {
            "code": "C1",
            "eyeColour": "brown",
            "name": "C1-name",
            "hierarchy": [
              
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "S2_blue": {
    "code": "S2",
    "eyeColour": "blue",
    "name": "David",
    "hierarchy": {
      "P2_blue": {
        "code": "P2",
        "eyeColour": "blue",
        "name": "Martha",
        "hierarchy": {
          "C1_brown": {
            "code": "C1",
            "eyeColour": "brown",
            "name": "C1-name",
            "hierarchy": [
              
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issues here are :

1. `hierarchy` inside `gp` should be an array but I am getting a object
2. Not 100% sure but because of above problem rather than having objects inside an array against `hierarchy` I am getting an object with key as `parent/child and eye colour` ( Ex : C1_black , P1_blue etc )

So not really sure how to get this part and I am having a tough time to visualise the recursive behaviour
Thanks in advance and once again really appreciate the help already provided by @Harshank and @sudhish_s

Comment: I have answered this in mulesoft help forum. LInk [MuleSoft Help Forum link](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D72T000004Nq7cSAC/detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered this in mulesoft help forum. LInk [MuleSoft Help Forum link](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D72T000004Nq7cSAC/detail)

Comment: Please edit the post to include the details of the answer here. Links can break and if they do your answer as it stands will become useless.